# How to filter IS NULL in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic, meta-search

I've a table with an integer column called "map_id", I want to add an activeadmin filter to filter if this column IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

How could this be implemented ?

I tried the following filter

```
filter :map_id, :label => 'Assigned', :as => :select, :collection => {:true => nil, :false => ''}
```

But, I get the following error message :

undefined method `map_eq' for #

Comment: I made some edits, if you have the permissions, please take a quick look and approve them. I think this is a rather common questions and it's wort having it out there with working info. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not found a good solution but here is a how.
filters of Active_admin are accomplished by meta_search, you can override the functions automatically generated by meta_search in your model to get the behavior that you want, the best way is to use the scope since you need to return a relation in order to chain with other query/scopes, as stated [here](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search)

in your model:

for :as=>:select filters, acitve_admin use the _eq wheres, here is the [source code](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/inputs/filter_select_input.rb)

```
scope :map_eq, 
        lambda{ |id|
        if(id !='none')
            where( :map_id=> id)
        else
            where( :map_id=> nil)
        end
        }

#re-define the search method:
search_method :map_eq, :type => :integer
```

in your ative_admin register block:

```
filter :map_id, :label => 'Assigned', :as => :select, :collection => [['none', 'none'], ['one', 1],['tow', 2]]

# not using :none=>nil because active_admin will igore your nil value so your self-defined scope will never get chained.
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I made some edits, if you have the permissions, please take a quick look and approve them. I think this is a rather common questions and it's wort having it out there with working info. Thanks for the initial lead, you made pretty much the whole solution! Thanks!

Comment: Another example: Nested in `ActiveAdmin.register MyModel`, you add `filter :available, :as => :select, :label => "Availability", :collection => { :Available => true, :Assigned => false }`.  Then, to implement the scope in MyModel: `search_method :available_eq; scope :available_eq, ->(_){ where("user_id is #{:not unless ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(_)} null") }`

Comment: Thank you, @gret -- Would not have figured out how to make my example work without your answer

Answer (score 38):

If anyone is happening on this thread belatedly, there is now an easy way to filter for null or non null in active admin :

```
filter :attribute_present, :as => :boolean 
filter :attribute_blank,   :as => :boolean
```

It is no longer necessary to add a custom method to the scope to accomplish this.

Comment: Note that this can cause SQL errors depending on the data type: it works best with string values and will break when used with datetimes.

Comment: And for anyone trying to apply the filter through the query string of a link, you would do admin_resources_path('q[attribute_blank]' => true)

Comment: For integer fields use *_null* or *_not_null* instead:

`filter :attribute_not_null, as: :boolean`

`filter :attribute_null, as: :boolean`

Comment: @Samuel-innovega answer works for datetimes/timestamps as well - for date/datetime fields use _null or _not_null
`filter :datetime_attr_null, as: :boolean`

Answer (score 5):

seems search_method doesn't work in recent rails version, here is another solution:

add scope to your model:

```
  scope :field_blank, -> { where "field is null" }
  scope :field_not_blank, -> { where "field is not null" }
```

add to /app/admin/[YOUR MODEL]

```
   scope :field_blank
   scope :field_not_blank
```

you will see buttons for these scopes appear (in top section, under model name, not in filter section)

Comment: Thanks, this saved my life. Note that ActiveAdmin's default setup doesn't provide a way to clear a scope, so if you want to reset the scope you should manually define an "Everything" scope and add that.

Answer (score 2):

The new version of ActiveAdmin uses Ransacker. I manage to got it working this way:

#### On the admin

```
filter :non_nil_map_id, :label => 'Assigned', :as => :select, :collection => [['none', 'none'], ['one', 1],['tow', 2]]
```

For consistency, I took the same code from @Gret answer just changing the filter name

#### On your model

```
ransacker :not_nil_map_id, :formatter => proc {|id|  map_id != 'none' ? id : 'none' } do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
end
```

This should trigger a search against *nil* in case the id is 'none', and active record will return all the *nil id* entries.

[This thread](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/36) helped **a lot**.

Answer (score -1):

With ransackable scopes:

**On the ActiveAdmin resource definition:**

```
filter :map_id, :label => 'Assigned', as: :select, :collection => [['Is Null', 'none'], ['Not null', 'present']]
```

**On your model:**

```
scope :by_map_id, ->(id) { (id == 'none' ? where(map_id: nil) : where('map_id IS NOT NULL')) }

def self.ransackable_scopes(_auth_object = nil)
  %i[by_map_id]
end
```